# Total values in a TextView and put the total in another textview for android

Tags: java, android, textview

I have some values in one textView. as example:

```
200
300
100
500
```

How to total up these values and put it in another textview? When i open the application, it stopped. Help me..3 days now i'm stuck here

This is the code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        textView.setText(100+"\n" + 200+"\n" + 300+"\n");

        String toParse = textView.getText().toString(); //get the text from the source textview
        String [] numbers = toParse.split("\\r?\\n");
        int total = 0;
        for(String s : numbers)
        {
            total += Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        textView1.setText(total); //set the text to the target textview
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100 200 300 400"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

btw, i'm still new to android.:D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text from your textview and split them by newline which is then stored in array and adding them by converting the string to integer

```
String toParse = tvObject.getText().toString(); //get the text from the source textview
String [] numbers = toParse.split("\\r?\\n");
int total = 0;
for(String s : numbers)
{
    total += Integer.parseInt(s);
}
secondTvObject.setText(total); //set the text to the target textview
```

Comment: i used your codes and updated my post. Is it correct to do that way?